# How can I create pop-up windows for Perl6 in Windows?

Tags: raku

I am using Windows 7 and 10 `rakudo-star-2019.03-x86_64 (JIT)`. I would like to know how I can create a pop up window in Perl6 to give information to the user?  Something like Linux's send-notify or Windows Pro msg (without the networking)

Many thanks,
-T

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is a simple Messagebox good enough? Then

```
use NativeCall;

constant WCHAR              = uint16;
constant INT                = int32;
constant UINT               = uint32;
constant HANDLE             = Pointer[void];
constant LPWCTSTR           = CArray[WCHAR];
constant MB_ICONEXCLAMATION = 0x00000030;

sub MessageBoxW( HANDLE, LPWCTSTR, LPWCTSTR, UINT ) is native('user32') returns INT { * };

MessageBoxW( my $handle, to-c-str("๘❤ Raku is awesome ❤๖"), to-c-str("Hellö Wαrld"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

sub to-c-str( Str $str ) returns CArray[WCHAR]
{
    my @str := CArray[WCHAR].new;
    for ( $str.comb ).kv -> $i, $char { @str[$i] = $char.ord; }
    @str[ $str.chars ] = 0;
    @str;
}
```

For anything more complex, the only option available right now for GUIs are [bindings for Tk](https://github.com/perl6/gtk-simple) I believe.

Comment: I will check it out tomorrow.  Thank you!  Is there a way to time out the message box?

Comment: I'm afraid not. But you want something else anyway.

Comment: I have found a python example that allegedly does show Toast notifications (how they call it): https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/blob/master/win10toast/__init__.py You could port that to raku using NativeCall if you are determined enough.

Comment: I had found GTK::Simple but could not get it to install.  Your comment made me look again.  I was missing git, which zef required (rakudo-star-2019.03-x86_64 (JIT).msi).  I reported it over at 'zef requires git" https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3333. Thank you!

Comment: @Todd There are circumstances in which there's a delay of a day or two before the green check mark (next to the answer's score) appears. (I think one of the circumstances is if you answer your own question.)

Comment: Hi Raiph,  It appeared and I checked it.  Thank you for the explanation.  -T

Answer (score 2):

I turned your example into a module.   Thank you!

```
# unit module WinMsg;
# WinMsg.pm6

#`{
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105696/how-can-i-create-pop-up-windows-for-perl6-in-windows
}

use NativeCall;

sub WinMsg( Str $TitleStr, Str $MessageStr ) is export( :WinMsg ) {

   constant WCHAR              = uint16;
   constant INT                = int32;
   constant UINT               = uint32;
   constant HANDLE             = Pointer[void];
   constant LPWCTSTR           = CArray[WCHAR];
   constant MB_ICONEXCLAMATION = 0x00000030;

   # Note: the following two subs have to be embedded

   sub MessageBoxW( HANDLE, LPWCTSTR, LPWCTSTR, UINT ) is native('user32') returns INT { * };

   sub to-c-str( Str $str ) returns CArray[WCHAR]  {
      my @str := CArray[WCHAR].new;
      for ( $str.comb ).kv -> $i, $char { @str[$i] = $char.ord; }
      @str[ $str.chars ] = 0;
      @str;
   }


    # MessageBoxW( my $handle, to-c-str("๘❤ Raku is awesome ❤๖"), to-c-str("Hellö Wαrld"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

    MessageBoxW( my $handle, to-c-str( $MessageStr ), to-c-str( $TitleStr ), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );
}
```

Test run line:

```
>perl6 -e "use lib '.'; use WinMsg :WinMsg; WinMsg( 'Super Duper Title', 'What? You were expecting something witty?' );"
```